# Ayuda con consultas de Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo mis siguientes consultas:

```
SELECT T0.ItemCode as Codigo,T0.ItemName as Descripción,  
sum(Convert(int,A.VPiezas)) as Cantidad, sum(Convert(money, 
(A.VPiezas)))/sum(Convert(money,(A.VPiezas))) as PrecioU 
FROM OITM T0
INNER JOIN OITT T1 ON T0.[ItemCode] = T1.[Code] 
INNER JOIN ITT1 T2 ON T1.[Code] = T2.[Father] 
INNER JOIN OITM T3 ON T2.[Code] = T3.[ItemCode] 
INNER JOIN [Ventas_catavina].dbo.SVenta A ON T3.ItemCode = Codigo1   
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS
WHERE T0.TreeType = 'T' and T3.ItmsGrpCod in (111)
group by T0.ItemCode, T0.ItemName
union
SELECT T3.ItemCode as Codigo, T3.ItemName as 
Descripción,sum(Convert(int,A.VKilos)) as Cantidad, null as PrecioU
FROM OITM T0
INNER JOIN OITT T1 ON T0.[ItemCode] = T1.[Code]
INNER JOIN ITT1 T2 ON T1.[Code] = T2.[Father] 
INNER JOIN OITM T3 ON T2.[Code] = T3.[ItemCode]
INNER JOIN [Ventas_catavina].dbo.SVenta A ON T3.ItemCode = Codigo1   
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS 
WHERE T0.TreeType = 'T' and T3.ItmsGrpCod in (111)
group by T3.ItemCode, T3.ItemName
```

Y me devuelven:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es que la fila con el valor nulo me aparezca abajo y no arriba.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta agregar un `ORDER BY` asi:

```
SELECT T0.ItemCode as Codigo,T0.ItemName as Descripción,  
sum(Convert(int,A.VPiezas)) as Cantidad, sum(Convert(money, 
(A.VPiezas)))/sum(Convert(money,(A.VPiezas))) as PrecioU 
FROM OITM T0
INNER JOIN OITT T1 ON T0.[ItemCode] = T1.[Code] 
INNER JOIN ITT1 T2 ON T1.[Code] = T2.[Father] 
INNER JOIN OITM T3 ON T2.[Code] = T3.[ItemCode] 
INNER JOIN [Ventas_catavina].dbo.SVenta A ON T3.ItemCode = Codigo1   
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS
WHERE T0.TreeType = 'T' and T3.ItmsGrpCod in (111)
group by T0.ItemCode, T0.ItemName
union
SELECT T3.ItemCode as Codigo, T3.ItemName as 
Descripción,sum(Convert(int,A.VKilos)) as Cantidad, null as PrecioU
FROM OITM T0
INNER JOIN OITT T1 ON T0.[ItemCode] = T1.[Code]
INNER JOIN ITT1 T2 ON T1.[Code] = T2.[Father] 
INNER JOIN OITM T3 ON T2.[Code] = T3.[ItemCode]
INNER JOIN [Ventas_catavina].dbo.SVenta A ON T3.ItemCode = Codigo1   
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS 
WHERE T0.TreeType = 'T' and T3.ItmsGrpCod in (111)
group by T3.ItemCode, T3.ItemName
ORDER BY PrecioU DESC
```

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió.